# Sum column values over a window and report the values of the previous window

Tags: r, plyr, zoo, rollapply

I´m having a data.frame of the following form:

```
ID  Var1   
1    1 
1    1
1    3
1    4
1    1
1    0
2    2
2    2
2    6
2    7
2    8
2    0
3    0
3    2
3    1
3    3
3    2
3    4
```

and I would like to get there:

```
ID  Var1  X  
1    1    0
1    1    0
1    3    0
1    4    5
1    1    5
1    0    5
2    2    0 
2    2    0
2    6    0
2    7    10
2    8    10
2    0    10
3    0    0
3    2    0
3    1    0
3    3    3
3    2    3
3    4    3
```

so in words: I´d like to calculate the sum of the variable in a `window = 3`, and then report the results obtained in the previous window. This should happen with respect to the `ID`s and thus the first three observations on every `ID` should be returned with 0, as there is no previous time period that could be reported.
For understanding: In the actual dataset each row corresponds to one week and the `window = 7`. So X is supposed to give information on the sum of `Var1` in the previous week.

I have tried using some `rollapply` stuff, but always ended in an error and also the window would be a rolling window if I got that right, which is specifically not what I need.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `rollapply`, the width argument can be a list which provides the offsets to use.  In this case we want to use the points 3, 2 and 1 back for the first point, 4, 3 and 2 back for the second, 5, 4 and 3 back for the third and then recycle.  That is, for a window width of k = 3 we would want the following list of offset vectors:

```
w <- list(-(3:1), -(4:2), -(5:3))
```

In general we can write `w` below in terms of the window width k.  `ave` then invokes `rollapply` with that width list for each ID.

```
library(zoo)

k <- 3
w <- lapply(1:k, function(x) seq(to = -x, length = k))
transform(DF, X = ave(Var1, ID, FUN = function(x) rollapply(x, w, sum, fill = 0)))
```

giving:

```
   ID Var1  X
1   1    1  0
2   1    1  0
3   1    3  0
4   1    4  5
5   1    1  5
6   1    0  5
7   2    2  0
8   2    2  0
9   2    6  0
10  2    7 10
11  2    8 10
12  2    0 10
13  3    0  0
14  3    2  0
15  3    1  0
16  3    3  3
17  3    2  3
18  3    4  3
```

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
DF <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Var1 = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
  0L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but am I getting this right: your approach works only for the pictured data frame? The actual dataframe has ~ 33.000 rows so defining "w" for all of these

Comment: w is defined in terms of k so k can be set to any value such as 3 or 7 and the number of rows in the data frame can be anything.  As stated in the answer and also in the rollapply help file the offsets are *recycled* to the required length.

Comment: Sorry for the question then, R beginner here. Function is working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

We could group by 'ID', create a new grouping column with window size of 3 using `gl`, then get the `summarized` output by taking the `sum` of 'Var1' and placing the 'Var1' in a `list`, get the `lag` of 'X' and `unnest`

```
library(dplyr) #1.0.0    
library(tidyr)    
df1 %>%
     # // grouping by ID
     group_by(ID) %>%
     # // create another group added with gl
     group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 3, n())), .add = TRUE) %>% 
     # // get the sum of Var1, while changing the Var1 in a list
     summarise(X = sum(Var1), Var1 = list(Var1)) %>%
     # // get the lag of X
     mutate(X = lag(X, default = 0)) %>% 
     # // unnest the list column
     unnest(c(Var1)) %>%
     select(names(df1), X)
# A tibble: 18 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
#      ID  Var1     X
#   <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     0
# 2     1     1     0
# 3     1     3     0
# 4     1     4     5
# 5     1     1     5
# 6     1     0     5
# 7     2     2     0
# 8     2     2     0
# 9     2     6     0
#10     2     7    10
#11     2     8    10
#12     2     0    10
#13     3     0     0
#14     3     2     0
#15     3     1     0
#16     3     3     3
#17     3     2     3
#18     3     4     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Var1 = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```